# Node Heroku WebSocket can't connect to external Websocket and listen

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I'm trying to connect and listen to an external Websocket from my Node server and while it works in development in production it won't work. I keep reading about setting up your own broadcasting socket in Heroku but nothing on listening to other sockets. Anyone know why I am getting blocked? I am not currently defining a PORT just a ws URI.

Thanks

Comment: You can't listen on arbitrary ports on Heroku. They give you _one_ port to use (via the `PORT` environment variable) and you _must_ bind a web server to it.

Comment: Hey Chris. Thanks for the reply on this issue. Any suggestions on other services that would allow that? Digital Ocean? It's tough to find info about this for some reason. Thanks again

Comment: Heroku is a platform as a service provider. Generally speaking, those probably won't let you bind to arbitrary ports. Digital Ocean offers a different kind of service. If you rent a VPS from them (or anybody, really) you should be able to bind to ports to your heart's content. But of course there's a lot more administrative overhead.